# Sharepoint 2010 css.txt in webpart not applied in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We converted from SharePoint 2010 to 2013.  We had a css.txt file added to a content editor webpart that gave us custom branding.  Since the conversion the branding is no longer working.  We cannot use Sharepoint Designer. Any insight on how to tackle this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

CSS files are usually in a CSS file, but that's beside the point. We'd need code of what your old site had by way of a css embed/script statement and what your new site has (assuming that you have that file moved to your 2013 site). Also, generally you don't want to do branding from a CEWP, you want to do that with a master page. It might be time for googling.

Or a consultant.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick response.

The CSS.txt file was actually created by a consultant and I spent several days googling. It was working fine until we went to SP 2013. I renamed the file to .css and added it to the Master page alternate css.  It is working!  :)